# Nested loops when using draw methods, having trouble figuring out how to set it up right

Tags: java, swing, paint

I need help figuring out how to draw a checkerboard/quilt like pattern in a nested for loop using draw method in java. My Lab assignment reads as follows. 
You must create a QuiltPattern Class and declare two objects of that class. The constructor for this class will accept a parameter that sets a characteristic of the object (like the color), Alternate those objects when drawing the quilt. Make sure that your quilt contains at least 5 blocks across and 7 down. Your QuiltPattern class should include a method called Draw() that draws the pattern on the screen at a specific location. You must use nested loops to draw the quilt. 
I have everything mostly written, but I'm having trouble getting a quiltlike/checkerboard like object drawn. I can't seem to get it to line up and so far I only have two rows that are offset. Any help or suggestions to get this to work in a nested loop would be much appreciated. I've been trying to find something similar to this and I haven't have much luck. What am I doing wrong?

This is my QuiltPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class QuiltPanel extends JPanel
{
    int x = 0, y = 0, count = 0;

private Quilt squareOne, squareTwo;

public QuiltPanel()
{
    squareOne = new Quilt(25, Color.blue, x+50, y);
    squareTwo = new Quilt(25, Color.green, x+25, y);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
    setBackground(Color.black);

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        for ( count = 0; count <= 10; count = count+1)
        {   if ( count % 2 == 0)
            {   if ( count <= 5)
                {   squareOne.draw(page);
                    squareOne = new Quilt(25, Color.blue, x, y);

                }
                else
                {   squareOne.draw(page);
                    squareOne = new Quilt(25, Color.blue, x, y+25);

                }

            }
            else
            {   if ( count <= 5)
                {   squareTwo.draw(page);
                    squareTwo = new Quilt(25, Color.green, x, y);

                }
                else
                {   squareTwo.draw(page);
                    squareTwo = new Quilt(25, Color.green, x, y+25);

                }

            }
            x=x+25;
        }
   }
}
```

This is my Quilt Class:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Quilt

{
  private int height, width, x, y;
  private Color color;

public Quilt(int size, Color newColor, int upperX, int upperY)
{
    width = size;
    height = size;
    color = newColor;
    x = upperX;
    y = upperY;

}

public void draw(Graphics page)
{
    page.setColor(color);
    page.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

public void setHeight(int size)
{
    height = size;
}

public void setWidth(int size)
{
    width = size;
}

public void setColor(Color newColor)
{
    color = newColor;
}

public void setX(int upperX)
{
    x = upperX;
}

public void setY(int upperY)
{
    y = upperY;
}

public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}

public Color getColor()
{
    return color;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}
}
```

And if you need it my QuiltPattern (JFrame):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class QuiltPattern
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("QuiltPattern");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.getContentPane().add(new QuiltPanel());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new QuiltPanel());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use squares to draw the checkerboard ? can't you use lines, that's should be straightforward

Comment: Also what does the "alternate those objects" mean ? Assuming one call to draw method will draw the entire quilt, next time alternate object will just be overwriting it.

Comment: It just says that it need to be at least 5 blocks across and 7 down alternating different designs. It needs to look like a quilt but a checkerboard is close enough to what I'm trying to accomplish. I just need to figure out how to repeat them in a loop column by column.

Comment: @11thdimension This project is based off of a project that's in Java Software Solutions 8th edition. The project in the book asks us to write a program that draws a quilt in which a simple pattern is repeated in a grid of squares. We then have to modify it so that it has alternating colors or whatever characteristics we would like. So that the final result is similar or recognizable to a quilt.

Comment: I think I got it, will post something soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Quilt class should be QuiltPattern class. So I just copied and pasted that code from Quilt to QuiltPattern, as it's said in the program that QuiltPattern will do the drawing and it will have 2 objects with different drawing properties.

It's always best to keep the Main class separate. I have created a new class QuiltMain to initialize the Frame and Panel. (It's all your code).

Changed the constructor of QuiltPattern (previously Quilt) to accept 2 arguments color and size as location of square should logically be passed to the draw() method itself.

And finally the loop to create the checkerboard pattern. There are in general 3 options.

Options 1.

```
int initX = getWidth() / 2 - (columnCount * squareSide) / 2;
int initY = getHeight() / 2 - (rowCount * squareSide) / 2;
int squareCount = rowCount * columnCount;

for(int i = 0; i < squareCount; i++) {
    int rowI = squareCount / rowCount;
    int colJ = squareCount % columnCount;

    //draw at (initX + colJ * squareSide, initY + colI * squareSide)
}
```

Option 2.

```
int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
int centerY = getHeight() / 2;

for(int colJ = -rowCount/2; colJ < rowCount/2; colJ++) { //condition will include <= when rowCount is odd
    for(int rowI = -columnCount/2; rowI < columnCount/2; rowI++) {//condition will include <= when columnCount is odd

    //draw at (centerX + colJ * squareSide, centerY + colI * squareSide)
}
```

Option 3:

```
int initX = getWidth() / 2 - (columnCount * squareSide) / 2;
int initY = getHeight() / 2 - (rowCount * squareSide) / 2;

for(int colJ = 0; colJ < rowCount; colJ++) {
    for(int rowI = 0; rowI < columnCount; rowI++) {

    //draw at (initX + colJ * squareSide, initY + colI * squareSide)
}
```

I went with the option 3 as it seemed easiest and most suitable one.

Working code:

QuiltMain

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class QuiltMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("QuiltPattern");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new QuiltPanel());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new QuiltPanel());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

QuiltPattern

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class QuiltPattern {
    private int height, width, x, y;
    private Color color;

    public QuiltPattern(int size, Color newColor) {
        width = size;
        height = size;
        color = newColor;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics page, int x, int y) {
        page.setColor(color);
        page.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void setHeight(int size) {
        height = size;
    }

    public void setWidth(int size) {
        width = size;
    }

    public void setColor(Color newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }

    public void setX(int upperX) {
        x = upperX;
    }

    public void setY(int upperY) {
        y = upperY;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

QuiltPanel

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

class QuiltPanel extends JPanel {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int rowCount = 7;
    int columnCount = 5;

    private QuiltPattern squareOne, squareTwo;

    public QuiltPanel() {
        squareOne = new QuiltPattern(25, Color.blue);
        squareTwo = new QuiltPattern(25, Color.green);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
        setBackground(Color.black);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        int count = 0;
        int squareSide = squareOne.getWidth();
        boolean firstOne = true;

        int quiltWidth = columnCount * squareSide;
        int quiltHeight = rowCount * squareSide;

        int initX = (getWidth() - quiltWidth) / 2;
        int initY = (getHeight() - quiltHeight) / 2;

            for(int colJ = 0; colJ < columnCount; colJ++) {
                for(int rowI = 0; rowI < rowCount; rowI++) {
                    int x = colJ * squareSide + initX;
                    int y =  rowI * squareSide + initY;
                    if(firstOne) {
                        squareOne.draw(page, x, y);
                    } else {
                        squareTwo.draw(page, x, y);
                    }
                    firstOne = !firstOne;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I was for sure off more than a little bit. Thank you so much for your help.